# ¿Como encontrar el componente mas cercano respecto a un punto dado en el evento OnTap (Android) Delphi?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-berlin, delphi-tokyo

Es algo difícil de explicar, pero lo que necesito es que al dar click sobre un item de un TreeView, pueda identificar el componente checkbox mas cercano en un determinado radio desde el punto que se toco. No se si me explico pero intentare explicarlo con esta imagen.
[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Supongamos el click fue dado en el punto ROJO de la imagen por lo que el checkbox (CUADRO VERDE) no fue tocado, por lo tanto no se activaría, pero necesito que aunque el checkbox no fue tocado el evento OnTap busque en un radio determinado si existe un componente checkbox y de ser así lo presione, me explico?, espero me puedan ayudar estoy usando Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Agrega lo que has tratado por favor. Estas usando android?

Comment: no he intentado nada no conozco funciones para llegar a la solución.